# How to make php str_pad for multiple condition?

Tags: php

I have a value like this
`building_id as MN, HS, FB`
`floor no as 1,2,3,4 etc,.`
`room no as 1,2,3,4, etc,.`
`reg_id as 0001,0002,0003 etc,.`

What I need is
I want to generate bench no using these three values like
`(BUILDING_ID + FLOOR_NO + ROOM_NO + REG_ID) as MN01020001, MN01020002`

I have tried the following query but not working

```
<?php echo $building_id.str_pad($floor_no, 2, STR_PAD_LEFT, '0').str_pad($room_no, 2, STR_PAD_LEFT, '0').''.str_pad($reg_id, 4, STR_PAD_LEFT, '0'); ?>
```

It is giving the output like this
`MN0001`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine, Please check your program caused any error.

```
str_pad($floor_no, '0', 2, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are not passing the parameters correctly try this

```
str_pad($floor_no, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```